# Cloud Run local emulator : how to configure memory and CPU?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm developing a Cloud Run service using `gcloud beta code dev` (the local emulator).

- Can I use CLI flags to set memory and CPU?

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/developing-a-cloud-run-service) say there should be a `.vscode/launch.json` file, but I can't tell

- does this file impact a service launched via `gcloud beta code dev`, or only from the vscode extension?
- the VSCode extension allows only up to 2048 MiB per instances; can I manually configure more in `launch.json`?  If not, can I configure more via `gcloud beta code dev` otherwise?
- Can I specify CPUs as well, or are these tied to RAM?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to configure the `service.yaml` file to set or update the memory allocation and CPU limit then run the command `gcloud beta code dev service.yaml` in your local emulator? Reference: [gcloud beta code dev](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/code/dev#SERVICE_CONFIG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud beta code dev` command takes Cloud Run service, builds it and runs it on the **local machine**. To [customize](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/developing-a-cloud-run-service#customizing_an_existing_launchjson_configuration) how your service is run, you can specify the following fields in your `.vscode/launch.json` file including your service name, port, and **resource limits**. You could also try to configure your `service.yaml` with gcloud beta code dev. As per [gcloud beta code dev](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/code/dev) doc:

> [SERVICE_CONFIG]
>
> service.yaml filename override. Defaults to the first file matching *service.dev.yaml then *service.yaml, if any exist. This path is relative to the --source dir.